# Data between executables (ANSI C, MFC 4.1)

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a structure and a member of it is char* *  (2d pointer). I allocate space from EXE1 and call EXE2 with the data. I use memcpy to get all data on EXE2. The memory address on both EXE is the same (lets say 0x013740b0), though the data of char** on EXE2 are not present. How can I retrieve the data on EXE2?

Thanks in advance,
SunScreen

Answer (score 6):

You can not share pointers like that as each exe is having its own virtual address space and whatever address you are seeing is not a physical address, it is virtual address. This virtual address will be translated into different physical addresses in different exes. You can use [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory) to share the data between different processes.

Answer (score 1):

[Naveen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420432/data-between-executables-ansi-c-mfc-4-1/1420454#1420454) is correct.

You can try something like this:

```
  HGLOBAL hglbBuf = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, buffer_size);
  if (  hglbBuf == NULL  ) {
    // ...
    return;
  }

  /* do something with the buffer */
  void* buf = (void*)GlobalLock(hglbBuf);
  // ...
  GlobalUnlock(hglbBuf);
```

Comment: No - GLobalAlloc is Global to the process (The difference with LocalAlloc became theoretical after the Win16->Win32 changeover). EXE2 has its own, distinct "Global" addresses.
--- Also, you don't need GlobalLock in Win32

Comment: @MSalters, I don't think so. For example, MSDN samples use GlobalAlloc to pass clipboard data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not refer to anoher memory address in another executable directly, if you want this behaviour you have to make shared dll and put your structure in a shared place

Comment: that won't work either as in an application each DLL has also it's own address space.

Comment: That's a quite dirty hack. Unlike proper shared memory, DLL shared data sections bypass the NT security model.